# For batch rendering multiple similar objects which is more performant, drawArrays(TRIANGLE_STRIP) with "degenerate triangles" or drawArraysInstanced?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

MDN states that:

> Fewer, larger draw operations will generally improve performance. If
>   you have 1000 sprites to paint, try to do it as a single drawArrays()
>   or drawElements() call.
>
> It's common to use "degenerate triangles" if you need to draw
>   discontinuous objects as a single drawArrays(TRIANGLE_STRIP) call.
>   Degenerate triangles are triangles with no area, therefore any
>   triangle where more than one point is in the same exact location.
>   These triangles are effectively skipped, which lets you start a new
>   triangle strip unattached to your previous one, without having to
>   split into multiple draw calls.

However, it is also commmonly recommended that for multiple similar objects one should use instanced rendered. For webGl2 something like `drawArraysInstanced()` or for webGl1 `drawArrays` with the `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension activated.

For my personal purposes I need to render a large amount of rectangles of the same width in a 2d plane but with varying heights (webgl powered charting application). So any recommendation particular to my usecase is valuable.

Comment: Here you're basically choosing if you want to send the data in vertex attributes or as an array of uniforms (which you will index with instance id). Sending the data in vertex attributes will require larger buffers, since you're duplicating data per-vertex of your quad, but I find it simpler than instancing.

Answer (score 0):

Degenerate triangles are generally faster than drawArraysInstanced but there's arguably no reason to use degenerate triangles when you can just make quads with no degenerate triangles.

While it's probably true that degenerate triangles are slightly faster than quads you're unlikely to notice that difference. In fact I suspect it wold be difficult to create an example in WebGL that would show the difference.

To be clear I'm suggesting manually instanced quads. If you want to draw 1000 quads put 1000 quads in a single vertex buffer and draw all with 1 draw call using either `drawElements` or `drawArrays`

On the other hand instanced quads using drawArraysInstances might be the most convenient way depending on what you are trying to do.

If it was me though I'd first test without optimization, drawing 1 quad per draw call unless I already knew I was going to draw > 1000 quads. Then I'd find some low-end hardware and see if it's too slow. Most GPU apps get fillrate bound (drawing pixels) before they get vertex bound so even on a slow machine drawing lots of quads might be slow in a way that optimizing vertex calculation won't fix the issue.

You might find [this](https://webglsamples.org/lots-o-images/index.html) and/or [this](https://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/index.html) useful

Answer (score 0):

You can take as a given that the performance of rendering has been optimized by the compiler and the OpenGL core.

### static buffers

If you have a buffers that are static then there is generally an insignificant performance difference between the techniques mentioned. Though different hardware (GPUs) will favor one technique over another, but there is no way to know what type of GPU you are running on.

### Dynamic buffers

If however when the buffers are dynamic then you need to consider the transfer of data from the CPU RAM to the GPU RAM. This transfer is a slow point and on most GPU's will stop rendering as the data is moved (Messing up concurrent rendering advantages).

On average anything that can be done to reduce the size of the buffers moved will improve the performance.

### 2D Sprites Triangle V Triangle_Strip

At the most basic 2 floats per vertex (x,y for 2D sprites) you need to modify and transfer a total of 6 verts per quad for `gl.TRIANGLE` (`6 * 2 * b = 48bytes` per quad. where `b` is bytes per float (4)). If you use (`gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP`) you need to move only 4 verts for a single quad, but for more than 1 you need to create the degenerate triangle each of which requires an additional 2 verts infront and 2 verts behind. So the size per quad is (`8 * 2 * 4 = 64bytes` per quad (actual can drop 2verts lead in and 2 lead out, start and end of buffer))

Thus for 1000 sprites there are 12000 doubles (64Bit) that are converted to Floats (32Bit) then transfer is 48,000bytes for `gl.TRIANGLE`. For `gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP` there are 16,000 doubles for a total of 64,000bytes transferred

There is a clear advantage when using triangle over triangle strip in this case. This is compounded if you include additional per vert data (eg texture coords, color data, etc)

### Draw Array V Element

The situation changes when you use `drawElements` rather than `drawArray` as the verts used when drawing elements are located via the indices buffer (a static buffer). In this case you need only modify 4Verts per quad (for 1000 quads modify 8000 doubles and transfer 32,000bytes)

### Instanced V modify verts

Now using elements we have 4 verts per quad (modify 8 doubles, transfer 32bytes).

Using `drawArray` or `drawElement` and each quad has a uniform scale, be rotated, and a position (x,y), using instanced rendering each quad needs only 4 doubles per vert, the position, scale, and rotation (done by the vertex shader).

In this case we have reduced the work load down to (for 1000 quads) modify 4,000 doubles and transfer 16,000bytes

Thus instanced  quads are the clear winner in terms of alleviating the transfer and JavaScript bottle necks.

Instanced elements can go further, in the case where it is only position needed, and if that position is only within a screen you can position a quad using only 2 shorts (16bit Int) reducing the work load to modify 2000 ints (32bit JS Number convert to shorts which is much quicker than the conversion of Double to Float)) and transfer only 4000bytes

### Conclusion

It is clear in the best case that instanced elements offer up to 16times less work setting and transferring quads to the GPU.

This advantage does not always hold true. It is a balance between the minimal data required per quad compared to the minimum data set per vert per quad (4 verts per quad).

Adding additional capabilities per quad will alter the balance, so will how often you modify the buffers (eg with texture coords you may only need to set the coords once when not using instanced, by for instanced you need to transfer all the data per quad each time anything for that quad has changed (Note the fancy interleaving of instance data can help)

There is also the hardware to consider. Modern GPUs are much better at state changes (transfer speeds), in these cases its all in the JavaScript code where you can gain any significant performance increase. Low end GPUs are notoriously bad at state changes, though optimal JS code is always important, reducing the data per quad is where the significant performance is when dealing with low end devices